# Cannot fetch or pull from Github with Eclipse (EGit) because wrong password is stored

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

The first time I entered the password for a pull pull request from Github with Eclipse (EGit) I probably mistyped it. Now it automatically uses this password and everytime I try to make pull / fetch or push to upstream I get a not authorized error. But I can't find anywhere how to fix the wrong credentials. Anyone who knows?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I think `Preferences > General > Security > Secure Storage > Clear Passwords` which clears everything. Or you can also selectively delete stuff from `<user directory>\.eclipse\org.eclipse.equinox.security\secure_storage`

Comment: I had to go into the 'Contents' tab and delete the git node under [Default Secure Storage]