# invalid username/password in egit when pushing changes to googlecode

Tags: eclipse, git, sts-springsourcetoolsuite, egit, google-code

I have a project hosted in googlecode with Git.

I'm using STS (SpringSource Tool Suite) with eGit.

I cloned the repository at home and I could commit & push the changes successfully.
I did the same thing at work and when I try to push the changes after commiting them, it shows the following error:

```
https://myuser@code.google.com/p/myproject/: Invalid username/password.
You may need to use your generated googlecode.com password; see https://code.google.com/hosting/settings
```

I entered the googlecode generated password when I first cloned the repository (as I did at home, and this error never showed up). I try entering it again and nothing changes.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 20):

Do as following:

Open Git repositories view, open "Remotes > origin > " and click "Change Credentials..."

Further reference: http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/209017/

Enjoy!

Comment: It didn't work for me..but Preferences > General > Security > Secure Storage > Clear Passwords worked as specified in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11744224/cannot-fetch-or-pull-from-github-with-eclipse-egit-because-wrong-password-is-s

Answer (score 1):

I resolved it by going to `Preferences > General > Security > Secure Storage > Contens` tab and deleting default secure storage for repository.