# Cannot fetch or pull from Github with Egit because wrong username is stored

Tags: eclipse, github, egit

There is a similar question about this. But basically, I tried to fetch from github and entered the wrong username. It is being saved somewhere and I cannot figure out where to change the credentials for the life of me.

Now every time I do a fetch, it errors with not authorized. Does anyone know where to change the credentials?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/11744224

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Preferences -> General -> Security -> Secure Storage -> Contents. You should be able to locate and delete your git repository URL and credentials in the tree there.

Comment: Thanks. But also is necessary to create a token on git page.